# Sending unicode with Selenium Webdriver on python

Tags: python, unicode, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with python for running tests on a website.

python 2.7.2 with latest Selenium

I can't figure out how to send unicode such as German "Umlaute" (öäüß) to an input form. As far as I know webdriver can handle unicode so this might be a python problem.

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.de")
i = u"hälp me"
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("INPUT[name=\"q\"]").send_keys(i)
```

This works without errors but does not send the "ä". Is there any further encoding/decoding required...?

Cheers

Comment: Presumably the HTML page has an encoding; encode the input to that encoding before calling `.send_keys()` might work? `google.de` sez it's encoded to `ISO-8859-1`, so try `.send_keys(i.encode('latin1')`.

Comment: what does it send instead of the ä sign?

Comment: it sends nothing instead of the ä. If google.de runs on `ISO-8859-1` I should be good with `i="hälp me"` since my file is encoded `# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-` but that throws an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 0: invalid start byte`. `i.encode("latin1")` doesn't work either - same error

Comment: I've also tried yahoo.de with is utf-8 encoded with the original code... no success. Also I've tried the Chrome webdriver but it gives the same error. Moreover, I've tried `i.decode("iso-8859-1").encode("utf-8")` with and without the `u` in the variable declaration. No success, I'm running out of ideas =(

Comment: something like this: `i = unicode(i, "utf-8")` maybe?

Comment: @equinoxel hmm interesting. now i get `i = unicode(i, "utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 1: invalid start byte` after declaring `i="hälp me"`. If I try `i=u"hälp me"` I get `i = unicode(i, "utf-8")
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`

Answer (score 5):

After some hours of trying I finally got it =)
Looks like my IDE (Komodo) caused the problem - after setting the encoding in preferences to latin-4 it works nicely in two different ways:

Declare string as unicode:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-4 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from sys import version_info

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://www.google.de")

i = u"hälp me"
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("INPUT[name=\"q\"]").send_keys(i)
```

Decode latin-4 and convert to unicode:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-4 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from sys import version_info

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://www.google.de")

i = "hälp me"
i = unicode(i.decode("iso-8859-4"))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("INPUT[name=\"q\"]").send_keys(i)
```

Thanks to everybody who helped me!

Cheers

Comment: (1) don't use non-ascii characters inside bytestrings (it is explicitly forbidden in Python 3). Either use `u''` unicode literals or add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top, to create Unicode string. (2) unrelated: use single quotes, to avoid escaping double quotes in Python source: `'[name="q"]'`. (3) use utf-8 encoding for your Python source  (configure your IDE/editors accordingly) unless you have a very good reason not to.